# VBA to click link on webpage with no HREF and contains same class name

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, automation

I'm attempting to use VBA to click a link on a webpage with no HREF and same class name. There quite a few other post that I've attempted to use before posting, but the scenario below is a little different. I'm finally able to click a link on the web page, but it isn't the right link. Is there a way to specify the correct link with the HTML below?

```
<div class="WA5O WK3O WE4O" data-automation-id="selectedItem_3005$3351">
    <ul class="WC4O"></ul>
    <div tabindex="0" title="Integration Events" class="gwt-Label WB5O WK3O" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-2" role="link" aria-label="Integration Events" data-automation-id="promptOption" data-automation-label="Integration Events">Integration Events</div>
    <ul class="WC4O"></ul>
</div>
<div class="WA5O WK3O WE4O" data-automation-id="selectedItem_3005$6010">
    <ul class="WC4O"></ul>
    <div tabindex="0" title="Mass Action on Integration Events" class="gwt-Label WB5O WK3O" id="promptOption-gwt-uid-244" role="link" aria-label="Mass Action on Integration Events" data-automation-id="promptOption" data-automation-label="Mass Action on Integration Events">Mass Action on Integration Events</div>
    <ul class="WC4O"></ul>
</div>
```

Below is my VBA code to use the current open Internet Explorer and click the link. FYI - There is another HTML code with the **same class.** Can someone help me select the link that has "Integration Events"?

```
Function GetIE() As Object
Dim ShellApp As Object, ShellWindows As Object
Dim IEObject As Object
Dim inputField As Object, e As Object, elements As Object, inputFields As Object, btSubmit As Object
'Start code to open current Internet Explorer
        Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        Set ShellWindows = ShellApp.Windows()
        Dim item As Object
        On Error GoTo 0
        Dim sName As String

           For Each ObjWind In ShellWindows
            'On Error Resume Next
             If (Not ObjWind Is Nothing) Then
                sName = ObjWind.Name
                 If sName = "Internet Explorer" Then
                    Set IEObject = ObjWind
                    Exit For  'No need to continue....
                 End If
             End If

            Next

        If IEObject Is Nothing Then Set IEObject = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'End code to open current Internet Explorer

'Now to attempt to click the link for integration event. This doesn't work for some reason.
'With IEObject.document
'    Set elements = .getElementsByTagName("div")
'    For Each e In elements
'        If (e.getAttribute("aria-label") = "Integration Events") Then
'            e.Click
'            Exit For
'        End If
'    Next e
'End With


'Below works, but it click the wrong link. Anyway to add more detail to select correct link?
 Set backbutton = IEObject.document.getElementsByClassName("gwt-Label WB5O WK3O").item(Index:=0)
 backbutton.Click

Set ShellApp = Nothing
Set GetIE = IEObject
End Function
```

Comment: what's wrong with using the id?  Is it dynamic? Also, are you sure these are clickable? You can use IEObject.document.querySelector("[title='Integration Events']").click as an attribute =value css selector to target node

Comment: QHarr the querySelector statement in place of the Set backbutton worked! Is there any way I can give you credit? I can post the full VBA code solution as well. I never tried using the id, and I'm not sure what code to use for the id. The link is definitely clickable. I'm not sure if it is dynamic. I'm new to VBA, so I'm sorry I don't understand if it's dynamic.

Comment: If it is not dynamic then the fastest way would be ieobject.document.querySelector("#promptOption-gwt-uid-2").click so you can try that and report back. If it is dynamic the value promptOption-gwt-uid-2 will change over time.

Comment: Hi @QHarr, thank you for this. The value of promptOption-gwt-uid-2 will change over time, so this is dynamic. Thank you for your help. Please let me know how I can give you credit if you'd like. Also, if I'm able and it is not against the rules on this forum, I'd like to inquire if you are open to tutoring.

Comment: I can close this as a duplicate. I am around to help sometimes in this SO room: [dawghaus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus), but not as frequently as I used to be.  It is not some much formal tutoring as I help, when available and on-line) with more in depth explanations of certain topics (rather than answer question which could be asked here and benefit everyone).

Comment: Thank you @QHarr. Yes, please close this as a duplicate as this post probably won't help anyone. Sorry for the duplicate post. I will go in the room for some help on VBA. Thank you!!

Comment: No worries. :-)